# Can't update data using class based view and django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I can't update userprofile instance using django form and a class based view. POST request is send with proper parameters, template is redirecting properly, but unfortunately userprofile is not updating.

Please notice that I'm new to Django, so every tips are welcome.

**models.py**:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    search_range = models.IntegerField(default=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**forms.py**:

```
class HomeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('search_range',)
```

**views.py**:

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home/home.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = HomeForm()

        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def post(self, request):
        form = HomeForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.userprofile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home:home')

        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

**urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view(), name='home')
]
```

**home.html**:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The code looks correct. How did you check that the user profile was not updated ? Did you check directly in database or according to some display ? It may also be a display issue. For instance, you don't pass the `instance` keyword argument to the form in you `get` action. So, I guess `search_range` is prefilled with default value (`150`).

Comment: @AntoinePinsard You're right, it was a display issue. I didn't notice that data is updating correctly in database. Passing instance in get methods form solved the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good. The user profile was likely saved but, since you don't pass the `instance` keyword argument to the form in the `get` method, `search_range` is prefilled with the default value (150).

```
def get(self, request):
    form = HomeForm(instance=request.user.userprofile)

    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```